# How do I change drive letter in ido mode (Emacs)?

Tags: emacs, ido-mode

I'm using Emacs on windows. My default folder is `c:/home`, but I want to edit my file in `d:/` how to do it in ido mode ? I tried `//` but that put me in `c:/`.

Currently, I use <kbd>C-f</kbd> (change back to normal find file mode), but that defeat the purpose of using ido mode in first place....

Comment: I just tried d:/ and that works for me ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As stated in a comment you just type "d:/" in the minibuffer while in ido-find-file. You don't need to be at the start of the string, it's intelligent enough to know what you're trying to do.

`C-x C-f` `d:/` `MyFile.txt`

will point you at the file `D:/MyFile.txt`

Comment: Likewise with ~/ on Windows.