# Opening file from some other drive when ido-mode is enabeled in emacs 24

Tags: emacs, ido-mode

In emacs 24 on windows 7, I have enable Ido-mode.

When hitting `C-x C-f` to visit a file, then in mini-buffer I cannot delete `C:\` as I want to open file from some other drive.

Comment: What happens if you just start typing the path with the different drive letter, e.g. C-x C-f d:/ etc?

Comment: Thanks it worked!

Just for someone how is facing the same issue
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050913/how-do-i-change-drive-letter-in-ido-mode-emacs?rq=1

Comment: duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050913/how-do-i-change-drive-letter-in-ido-mode-emacs